# When I click the "Calculate" button, how can it get the values in each box A,B and pass those value to server to calculate and alert() the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I want to do a simple sum calculation GUI. The website will prompt the user input variable A,B and send to server ( c++ file will do the job ) to calculate and A+B return result by alert().
I have 2 input boxes "variable A" and "Variable B". When I click the "Calculate" button, how can it get the values in each box A,B and pass those value to server to calculate and alert() the result? 
I am using js and react-bootstrap to develop the website. 
[image]

Comment: How is `npm` related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some kind of XMLHttpRequests as mentioned above. You could choose any one of the many XHR libraries out there or use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

You can refer to the following [link](http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/) to better choose a particular solution according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), on how to post data to your server.

You'll have to make [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) from the browser to your server.